# jQuery using 'this' but just for the class?

Tags: jquery, this

I'm not sure if this is easily possible, but would be really handy if there's a simple way to do this.

If I had a list of elements are used to toggle on and off different div's, I can write a clumsy bit of jQuery below that does the trick:

```
<ul>
  <li class="classone">Show or Hide 1</li>
  <li class="classtwo">Show or Hide 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="classone">Div 1</div>
<div class="classtwo">Div 2</div>

<script>
  $('li.classone').click(function() {
    $('div.classone').toggle();
  });
  $('li.classtwo').click(function() {
    $('div.classtwo').toggle();
  });
</script>
```

...but it would be a lot nicer to use **this** but just for the class. Like:

```
$('li.this').click(function() {
  $('div.this').toggle();
});
```

Which I know doesn't work. It must be possible with a little + in there somewhere, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the class from the element and use in the selector:

```
$('li.classone,li.classtwo').click(function() {
  $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: what if the `li` has more than one class?

Comment: +1, but this will only work if the classes on the li's are a single class. @jim, instead of `class` why not use a `data-toggle-div` attribute?

Comment: @Jason: Then it won't work. If you specify what you would like that to do, it would probably be easy to implement.

Comment: @guffa i'm not the OP, i dunno what he wants ;)

Comment: @Jason: I know that you're not the OP, but I though that you might have an opinion on what would be the result in that case. :)

Answer (score 0):

this may break if you have multiple classes

```
<script>
$('li.classone').click(function() {
    $('div.'+$(this).attr('class')).toggle();
});
$('li.classtwo').click(function() {
    $('div.'+$(this).attr('class')).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions to grab the class from the clicked item are valid, but as some have commented, it will break if the li has multiple classes. It also gets a bit messy if you start doing this for a great deal of classes.

I think it's better approached from different angle which is flexible for situations where the li has many classes, and consolidates the common behavior to a common class. I've called that class toggle. I've left the original classes on the li so as not to change more of your markup than necessary, but if you were only using it for the click selector it could be removed.

```
<li class="toggle" data-targetclass="classone">One</li>
<li class="toggle" data-targetclass="classtwo">Two</li>
```

Use the common toggle class to bind all of the lis that should trigger the behavior, but then use the specific data- attribute to determine which div to toggle.

```
$('li.toggle').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).data('targetclass');
    $('div.' + target).toggle();
});
```

**EDIT**: You can see this live and tested on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbHrN/1/).

**EDIT 2**: If you only have one div of each class, you could use ids instead of classes. Put an id on each div, a data-targetid attribute on the lis, and use the #id selector in the click handler.